# Как обрабатывать команды pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Подскажите как обрабатывать фото и текст в зависимости от команд? Не могу разобраться как это делать.
Например:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['find_faces'])
def get_photo(message):

    # здесь я хочу найти лица на фото
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправь мне фото')
     #обработка фото
     #отправка результата в чат 

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['remove_background'])
def get_photo(message):
     # здесь я хочу удалить фон на фотке.
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправь мне фото')
     #обработка фото
     #отправка результата в чат
```

Вопрос: как отслеживать фото в чате в зависимости от команд?